# Why do Ruby developers appear not to use UML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uml

I always hear about UML being used in Java projects but never in Ruby ones. Is this just a cultural difference or is there less of a need for modeling in Ruby development because it's part of a more 'agile' culture?

Comment: You could probably generalize this question to "Why don't Ruby developers document their projects?

Comment: ...by which I think cletus means, this question is needlessly stereotypical

Comment: Wouldn't it be more valuable to ask what the benefits of modeling a project in UML are?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Obviously you can't generalize this to everybody, but programmers in languages like Ruby and Python tend to be less drawn to large design documents and UML because they view their language of choice as being concise and expressive enough that it isn't always necessary. There's a feeling of, "I could spend time and plot all this out in UML...or I could just write some Python that actually implements the design and expresses it in a language I like to read and lots of people *can* read." Java programs tend to feel "heavier" than their Ruby or Python counterparts — it's part of the design of the language.

Note that I'm not saying this is true of *your* project or even that it's true at all as a whole — this is just what I've observed about these programming cultures.

Comment: A kind of blunt way of expressing this would be to say that if your coworkers need a cartoon drawing of your code to understand it, then you need to either write better code or hire better coworkers.

Comment: @Jorg - we can also say, rather bluntly, that if someone think that code is the only thing needed for understanding large, complex systems, that person hasn't had that much of exposure to systems that do require that type of modeling up front. Everytime I've seen people saying that the code is enough to understand the system, hilarity and pain ensues (and usually goes hand to hand to horrible coding). Beyond a certain size, it is just not possible to rely on code only for understanding a large system, even if the code is written flawessly. We have known that for, what, 30 years now?

Answer (score 19):

Call me crazy but UML isn't for me regardless of the application stack.

Answer (score 14):

(Note, tongue sometimes placed in cheek.)

Probably one of the biggest cultural differences is that Java is often used in projects with large numbers of programmers, led by PHBs, where the high-level system design is done by people with the title "software architect". On these sort of projects the people in the "software architect" role will often generate a large amount of documentation (including UML relationship and state diagrams) during the initial planning phase of the project. These and other documentation artifacts are then expected to be implemented by the hordes of non-architect-programmers.

Ruby on the other hand, is the new hotness and is therefore more often chosen by people who want to program in it. Since the "architect" is the implementer, there is less need for complex upfront documentation. The implementers jot a few notes on general design guidelines and then sit down to program rather than designing upfront for others to program.

This isn't to say that you won't find a few scattered UML diagrams here or there in projects built in Ruby or other snazzy languages -- such as when someone is trying to describe a complex concept -- but such things just aren't needed as much if you are doing the work yourself.

Comment: There is a story told that Walt Disney never used story boards.  He would simply tell the story and then work work with the animators to make it happen.  When Mr. Disney passed away the team tried to continue this approach since it had been so effective, but found that they could not makes things work without the storyboards.  They reached the conclusion that they had always had storyboards, but that previously they had been embodied in Walt Disney himself.

Comment: @john Completely agree with the story. I usually say that "to model or not to model" is the wrong question (http://bit.ly/bOmEl). We all and always create a mental model of the system before coding it.the real discussion is whether the effort of making the models explicit is worth or not

Answer (score 6):

One of the obvious reasons is that well-designed Ruby programs rely heavily on Mixins, which AFAIK simply cannot be modeled in UML at all. I know that Schärli et al developed an extension to UML that can represent Traits which given the close relationship between Traits and Mixins could probably be adapted or just reused for representing Mixins, but then it's not UML anymore.

Comment: Interesting point. Couldn't you use Mixins as if they were interfaces, in a sense?

Comment: Mixins contain implementation while Interfaces only the interface and it's the class that has to implement them. So that's quite a difference.

Comment: @Vojto @Yar: If you want to compare a Mixin to a Class, then you could say that a Mixin is a Class which can appear multiple times in multiple places in the inheritance tree/graph and whose Superclass is pluggable. That's a much closer analogy than the "interface + implementation" one. Both are hard to model in UML, although I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Regarding UML as comprised of the MOF meta-metadmodel (M3) and the UML metamodel (M2), UML can be a fairly flexible language. Although there may be – in short – "differences" in and among UML modeling platforms, as in regards to UML profile (M1) compatibility, but it should be possible to model Ruby mixins in UML, anyway. In order to provide a proof of concept, in which regards, there might be a question as to "Which UML platform to use?" I would recommend either Modelio or Papyrus. Papyrus might integrate well with other Eclipse plugins. Modelio is built as a branded Eclipse distribution.

Answer (score 4):

This is a comment to the answer about mixins.  Mixins can actually be modelled in UML quite easily using many different methods.  Typically one uses multiple inheritance, interfaces or stereotypes (or any combination of these).  Choosing the method depends on the project and personal taste - let us not forget that the main reason for modeling is to conquer complexity, better understand reality and communicate more effectively so each model needs to fit a particular problem and audience.  Models are, by definition, pragmatic and so must be the process of creating them.

Let us not forget that UML is extensible using profiles and stereotypes.  Such extended UML is still valid UML.

In general, UML is more expressive and less restrictive than programming languages so if something can be written down in some programming language, it can also be done in UML.

Comment: `This is a comment` then add it as... a comment?

Comment: Would make sense, wouldn't it Doorknob?  Unfortunatelly, stackoverflow prevents users who haven't posted before (and thus haven't gathered enough "rep") from doing so.